# How to use strtok to separate specific string to array by two delimiter

Tags: c, split, strtok

I have strings like this `+100+200,300+500+400,700,900`. I need to split the string to array by two different symbols `'+'` and `','`, so I would like to get `A`'s `id = 100` and it's child `arrayA` `[200, 300]`, `B`'s `id = 500` and it's child `arrayB` `[400,700,900]`.

What is the best way to do it ?

Thanks.

I have the example code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct _example_s {
    unsigned short id;
    unsigned short child_id[5];
} example_t;

int main(void)
{
    example_t ex_ary[2]; //it means A and B

    char msg[30] = "+100+200,300+500+400,700,900";

    char *result = NULL;

    result = strtok(msg, "+,");

    while(result != NULL ) {
        printf("%s\n", result);
        result = strtok(NULL, "+,");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you could use `strpbrk()`, but I think you should use 2 `strtok_r`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct _example_s {
    unsigned short id;
    unsigned short child_id[5];
} example_t;

int main(void)
{
    example_t ex_ary[2]; //it means A and B
    size_t index;
    char msg[30] = "+100+200,300+500+400,700,900";
    char *result = NULL;
    char *plusSign;

    memset(ex_ary, 0, sizeof(ex_ary));

    index  = 0;
    result = strtok_r(msg, "+", &plusSign);
    while (result != NULL )
    {
        char  *comma;
        char  *array;
        size_t element;

        ex_ary[index].id = strtol(result, NULL, 10);
        result           = strtok_r(NULL, "+", &plusSign);
        element          = 0;
        if (result != NULL)
        {
            array = strtok_r(result, ",", &comma);
            while (array != NULL)
            {
                ex_ary[index].child_id[element++] = strtol(array, NULL, 10);
                array                             = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &comma);
            }
        }
        index += 1;
        result = strtok_r(NULL, "+", &plusSign);
    }

    for (index = 0 ; index < 2 ; ++index)
    {
        size_t i;

        printf("id: %d\n", ex_ary[index].id);
        for (i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i)
        {
            printf("\t%d\n", ex_ary[index].child_id[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I think it's what you need.

Comment: Thanks @iharob, it's what i need.
That's pretty tips that I have never know of that. I'll try to understand strtok_r.